# Reverse Geocoding Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, reverse-geocoding, zipcode

I currently have a DataFrame with columns for "Latitude" (float) and "Longitude" (float) and I want to create a column "ZipCode" with the belonging zip codes.

So far I have the following code:

```
location = geolocator.reverse("41.750722, -73.997276")
geo_string = location.address.split(",")
geo_string[-2]
```

However, I cannot figure out how to run it for each row in the DataFrame. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your dataframe looks like, but I believe you should be able to use `.iterrows()`:

````
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    location = geolocator.reverse("{}, {}".format(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']))
    geo_string = location.address.split(",")
    geo_string[-2]```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with geopy. But assuming geolocator is defined, you can do an one-liner like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[41.750722, -73.997276]], columns=["Latitude", "Longitude"])
df["ZipCode"] = df.apply(lambda x:geolocator.reverse(str(x["Latitude"])+", "+str(x["Longitude"])).address.split(",")[-2], axis=1)
```